# clear:both affected by outside floated elements?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs. the red is `float:left` ( width:100px)

The green div is `margin-left:101px` ( *not* floated)

[image]

In the **green** div I added a `div` with 2 floated elements :

[image]

So the result  is :

[image]

All ok.

But If I add a `div` with `clear:both` here :

[image]

It is stretched  **beyond** the bottom of the  red `div`  :

[image]

My question  is **why** is that ?

I know that `clear:both` should *not* allow any floated elements at both and right location **But under the same container** !!

we are talking about the green div container here. why does the clear:both is also consider the red div ? it's out of his scope !

any help ?

*(Im looking for the reason. Also  - how can I change the `clear:both` to work as desire )*

(http://jsbin.com/oQEXANOK/3/edit)

p.s.

*The css of red and green divs is mandatory. that's how the site is currently built.*

## edit :

I found that if I put `float:left` on this :

[image]

It behaves as it should :

[image]

(what is going on here... ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to replace margin-left to float:left

Comment: I guess I'm writing `p.s.` for nothing..... ( and you don't explain the weird behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find out why its acting like that but if you give float left to lightgreen div everything comes as expected.

Comment: @RoyiNamir We got it at the same time :)